# Depend on ros package in catkin package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to depend on a ros package in my catkin package, but this does not seem to work (or at least not in the same way as with another catkin package).

I tried adding build_depend and run_depend in the catkin package for the ros package, and added it to:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS <packages>)
```

but then I get the error :

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "<some ros package>" with any
  of the following names:
```

So my question now is, can I depend on a ros package in a catkin package, and if so, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55331/depend-on-ros-package-in-catkin-package/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin packages are also ROS packages (usually). What you mean maybe is a rosbuild package (having manifest.xml). And no, catkin packages cannot depend on rosbuild packages, it only works the other way round. So if you want to build a package that depends on a rosbuild package, your package has to be a rosbuild package, too.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-15**:
I was afraid that would be the answer. Since ROS appears to be moving towards catkin build packages, the best solution would be to convert this rosbuild package to a catkin build package?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-02-15**:
You can only do that if all the packages your package depends on are already using catkin. Else they need to be converted before.